# How to efficiently count matches across a list in R?

Tags: r, list, performance, data.table, match

I have a list of vectors of integers, for example:

```
set.seed(1)

vec_list <- replicate(100, sample(1:10000000, size=sample(1:10000, 100)), simplify=FALSE)
```

And a vector of integers, for example:

```
vec <- sample(1:10000000, size=10000)
```

How can I count the number of intergers in each vector in *vec_list* that appear in the vector *vec*? I can do this using a for loop. For example:

```
total_match <- rep(NA, length(vec_list))

for (i in 1:length(vec_list)){
  total_match[i] <- length(which(vec_list[[i]] %in% vec))
  print(i)
}
```

However, the list and vector I am trying to apply this too are very large, and this is slow. Please help with suggestions on how to improve performance.

Using data.table is much faster, but does not return 0's when there are no matches. For example:

```
DT <- data.table(repid=rep(1:length(vec_list), sapply(vec_list, length)), val=unlist(vec_list))
total_match2 <- DT[.(vec), on=.(val), nomatch=0L, .N, keyby=.(repid)]$N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
DT <- setDT(stack(setNames(vec_list, 1:length(vec_list))))
DT[, x := +(values %in% vec)][, sum(x), keyby=.(ind)]$V1
```

Comment: Rcpp version might be even faster but in subsequent sections of your code, u r prob better off staying with data.table rather than code everything in C/C++

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
sapply(vec_list, function(x) sum(x %in% vec))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, a variant of @chinsoon's:

```
nvec = 5000
max_size = 10000
nv = 10000000

set.seed(1)
vec_list <- replicate(nvec, sample(nv, size=sample(max_size, 1)), simplify=FALSE)
vec <- sample(nv, size=max_size)

system.time(
  res <- rbindlist(lapply(vec_list, list), id=TRUE)[.(vec), on=.(V1), nomatch=0, .N, keyby=.id]
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.86    0.20    0.47 


system.time({
  DT <- setDT(stack(setNames(vec_list, 1:length(vec_list))))
  res2 <- DT[, x := +(values %in% vec)][, sum(x), keyby=.(ind)]$V1
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.03    0.45    1.00 


identical(res2[res2 != 0], res$N) # TRUE
```

Comment: And maybe adding `[ .(ID=seq_len(nvec)), on=.(ID)][is.na(N), N := 0L]` to complete the list for no matches